# Delete a single row from displayed data on userform VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I've built a userform in VBA to display a list of items from row 1 to 250. What I'd like to do is add the option of deleting any one row using the userform by clicking on a button corresponding to that row (and if possible, to move the remaining rows up by one). Is that possible?

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim rngData As Range
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngCol As Long

Set rngData = Sheets("MAIN").Range("W1:X250")
With ListBox1
    .ColumnCount = rngData.Columns.count

    For lngRow = 1 To rngData.rows.count
        For lngCol = 1 To rngData.Columns.count
            If lngCol = 1 Then
                .AddItem rngData.Cells(lngRow, lngCol).Text
            Else
                .List(lngRow - 1, lngCol - 1) = rngData.Cells(lngRow, lngCol).Text
            End If
        Next
    Next


End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, let's say you add a `CommandButton` and once you click it you read the `ListIndex` out of `ListBox1` selected item (allowing a deletion of one row).

**Sub *CommandButton1*_Click** (inside the User_From Code module)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim RowtoDel    As Long

' listindex starts from 0, while your range starts from 1 >> add 1
RowtoDel = Me.ListBox1.ListIndex + 1

Sheets("MAIN").Rows(RowtoDel).Delete

End Sub
```